# C# WebException Error: 530 (not logged in)

Tags: c#, ftp, webexception

I need some help with some code that is not working for some reason.  I'm making a method that gets a list of files in a FTP directory.  Every time I debug the app, a WebException is thrown with the StatusCode of 530 (not logged in).  <strike>Keep in mind that I am 100% positive the address, username, and password are correct.</strike>  Here's the method:

```
public static List<string> GetFileList(string Directory)
    {
        List<string> Files = new List<string>();
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ServerInfo.Root + Directory));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServerInfo.Username, ServerInfo.Username);
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); //Error occurs here
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string CurrentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentLine))
        {
            Files.Add(CurrentLine);
            CurrentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return Files;
    }
```

This is the value of ServerInfo.Root:  "ftp://192.xxx.4.xx:21/MPDS" (partially censored for privacy)

I have used MessageBoxes to ensure the complete URI is correct, and it is.

I've been struggling with this problem for a long time now, so I hope you can help me fix it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code with some corrections:

```
public static List<string> GetFileList(string Directory)
    {
        List<string> Files = new List<string>();

        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ServerInfo.Root + Directory));
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServerInfo.Username, ServerInfo.Username); // Is this correct?
        // request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServerInfo.Username, ServerInfo.Password); // Or may be this one?

        request.UseBinary = false;
        request.UsePassive = true;

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        string CurrentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentLine))
        {
            Files.Add(CurrentLine);
            CurrentLine = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
        return Files;
    }
```

Comment: While reading your revised code, `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ServerInfo.Username, ServerInfo.Username);` is the problem.  I replaced the second ServerInfo.Username to .Password and it works perfectly now.  Thanks so much!